# Mathjax version of \DeclareMathSymbol - How to make a certain character use a different font variant?

Tags: mathjax

Sometimes in LaTeX I'll have a bunch of stuff written up with just `e` for Euler's constant, instead of using `\mathrm{e}` or making a macro for it, but I want it to display in roman font as constants should, so in LaTeX I'd do something like:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{constants}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{e}{\mathalpha}{constants}{`e}
```

which makes any `e` in math mode display as a constant (which is fine because I don't normally call any variables e).

My question is: how can I do this in MathJax? I don't want to go through all the stuff I've written up and change all the `e`s to some macro; I want to configure MathJax to automatically display that character in roman font. So for example `$abcde$` should display with abcd italic, but the e should be roman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to add

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
(function () {
  var MML;
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("mml Jax Ready",function () {
    MML = MathJax.ElementJax.mml;
  });
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
    var TEX = MathJax.InputJax.TeX;
    TEX.Definitions.special["e"] = "myConstant";
    TEX.Parse.Augment({
      myConstant: function (c) {
        this.Push(this.mmlToken(MML.mi(c).With({mathvariant:MML.VARIANT.NORMAL})));
      }
    });
  });
})();
</script>
```

just before the script tag that loads `MathJax.js` itself.  This marks the letter "e" as a special character that causes your `myConstant` function to be called (being passed the "e", so you could attach other letters to `myConstant` to get them to be in Roman).  The `myConstant` function creates an `<mi>` element with `mathvariant="normal"` containing the given character, and pushes that on the TeX processing stack.